# Using Expect to fill a password in a bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I am relatively new to working in bash and one of the biggest pains with this script I have to run is that I get prompted for passwords repeatedly when running this script.  I am unable to pass ssh keys or use any options except expect due to security restrictions but I am struggling to understand how to use expect.

Does Expect require a separate file from this script to call itself, it seems that way looking at tutorials but they seem rather complex and confusing for a new user. Also how do I input into my script that I want it to auto fill in any prompt that says Password: ? Also this script runs with 3 separate unique variables every time the script is called. How do I make sure that those are gathered but the password is still automatically filled?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
zero=`echo $2`
TMPIP=`python bin/dgip.py $zero`
IP=`echo $TMPIP`
folder1=`echo $zero | cut -c 1-6`
folder2=`echo $zero`
mkdir $folder1
cd $folder1
mkdir $folder2
cd $folder2
scp $1@`echo $IP`:$3 .
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Thanks ill check that out but it doesnt show me how to implement using expect. I haven't tried using expect in the script I applied but I have been miserably failing at different attempts to make that happen. I think I am just not comprehending the basics and most tutorials I find are either lacking in detail or way more complex than it seems they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding expect code in an shell script is not too difficult. We have to be careful to get the quoting correct. You'll do something like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user=$1
zero=$2
files=$3

IP=$(python bin/dgip.py "$zero")

mkdir -p "${zero:0:6}/$zero"
cd "${zero:0:6}/$zero"

export user IP files

expect <<<'END_EXPECT'        # note the single quotes here!

    set timeout -1
    spawn scp $env(user)@$env(IP):$env(files) .
    expect {assword:}
    send "$env(my_password)\r"
    expect eof

END_EXPECT
```

Before you run this, put your password into your shell's exported environment variables:

```sh
export my_password=abc123
bash script.sh joe zero bigfile1.tgz
bash script.sh joe zero bigfile2.tgz
...
```

Having said all that, public key authentication is much more secure. Use that, or get your sysadmins to enable it, if at all possible.